# Using xslt for each group

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to use XSLT 2.0 to group records based on a field and create a "group id" for each record

I tried creating this XSLT

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/*">
 <Hire>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="XRefCode">
   <group name="{current-grouping-key()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
   </group>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </Hire>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All I am getting is the root node in the output.

This is the input

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Data>
<Record>
    <H1>D</H1>
    <Employee>Employee</Employee>
    <Employee1>Employee</Employee1>
    <XRefCode>012912</XRefCode>
    <EmployeeNumber>012912</EmployeeNumber>
</Record>
<Record>
    <H1>D</H1>
    <Employee>Employee</Employee>
    <Employee1>Employee</Employee1>
    <XRefCode>09090</XRefCode>
    <EmployeeNumber>012912</EmployeeNumber>
</Record>
<Record>
    <H1>D</H1>
    <Employee>Employee</Employee>
    <Employee1>Employee</Employee1>
    <XRefCode>012912</XRefCode>
    <EmployeeNumber>012912</EmployeeNumber>
</Record>
<Record>
    <H1>D</H1>
    <Employee>Employee</Employee>
    <Employee1>Employee</Employee1>
    <XRefCode>09090</XRefCode>
    <EmployeeNumber>012912</EmployeeNumber>
</Record>
     </Data>
```

Comment: Works fine for me with your original code and input at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuP5 so you might have some different input (namespaces?) and/or you might not use an XSLT 2 processor.

Comment: You are right. It should be working. Thank you!